# Maven soa Testing using soa plugin

Tags: oracle, maven, soa

I am running a SOA test using maven with soa plugin from my local windows machine.The test is successful but after few minutes there is heavy load on the server and the server goes down. What am I doing wrong here?

Command

> mvn oracle-soa:test

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted all the previous instances for this composite and then it worked!